# Php microseconds in relative templates

Tags: php, reference, seconds, datetime

I have a date time object which I would like to modify the microseconds. I'm using the following code.

```
 $datesArray[$alreadyDoneIndices+$countIndices]->modify("+$microsecondIncrementAmount mseconds");
```

and I'm getting the following error message.

```
DateTime::modify() [datetime.modify]: Failed to parse time string (+38462 microseconds) at position 3 (4): Unexpected character in C:\xampp\htdocs\DynamicUpdating\timelineUpdater.php on line 147
```

What's not working with this? Is there a reference for what relative timestamps work in php that I'm missing if that is the problem?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot use mseconds http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php and http://dk2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php

Answer (score 0):

Just check mseconds in modify("+$microsecondIncrementAmount mseconds") The error message tells you that the time string is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$datesArray[$alreadyDoneIndices+$countIndices]->modify("+{$microsecondIncrementAmount} mseconds");
```

Notice the {}